# Confused about how Silverlight gets onto the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight

I have spent a while going over all of the examples on http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/

And I'm still pretty lost about Silverlight. I'm not understanding exactly how it gets 'on' to the website. Like... is there any kind of tutorial that shows how you make an HTML webpage that retrieves a silverlight page and displays it, so you can work with it?

All I've had to work with so far are the default generated .aspx files, which don't really tell me much. And even using the default 'MVC Application' generator from Visual Studio is kind of cloudy and fuddled up.

I've done some google searches and glanced around at references, but maybe I'm just kind of dumb. I'm just not getting where it all 'comes together', so to speak. Any hints? Or am I just beyond learning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189089%28VS.95%29.aspx) is the Microsoft tutorial on Embedding Silverlight into HTML. The .xap is the equivalent to Jnlp for modern applets and .swf for Flash. The parameters can control the code and can also be updated via Javascript. The silverlight plugin within the browser executes the application code. HTML just holds it in place.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is that you include Silverlight applications in a web page by using an object tag in HTML.  The web browser is then responsible for loading the silverlight application similar to the way it loads Flash applications.  Check out these [quickstarts](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/getting-started-with-silverlight/) for a more detailed explanation.  Don't be discouraged, this is a new concept to a lot of developers :).

Here is an example of a Silverlight application being embedded in a web page:

```
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
     <div id="silverlightControlHost">
       <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," 
               type="application/x-silverlight-2" 
               width="100%" height="100%">
          <param name="source" value="HelloWorld.xap"/>
          <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
          <param name="background" value="white" />
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
          <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0" 
                   style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" 
                   alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
          </a>
       </object>
       <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame"
               style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px">
       </iframe>
     </div>
   </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I've done all that, and I just don't get it. It makes one .xaml file and I can't do anything with it. Making a program is useless if I can only have one file, truthfully. I've looked at the <object> tags and it doesn't give any indication about what 'page' it is loading... I've done every one of the quickstarts, and they just don't make any sense.

Comment: Yes but that references the entire application. What is the point of different pages if I can only reference the single one?

Comment: @Stacey It is not loading a page it is loading the application data similar to flash loading swf, or an applet loading jar's. So the stuff is in "data:application/x-silverlight-2".

Comment: the XAP is a container for all the XAML pages contained within. Navigation is done completely within that frame.

Comment: When you create a new Silverlight project in Visual Studio, it should ask you if you want to create an ASP.NET site to host the application.  gmcalab describes the process below this answer.  If you do it that way, it should wire up everything for you, and anything you implement in the Silverlight project should show up when you run the web project.  Can you tell us where exactly you're getting stuck?  You should be able to add more XAML files to your solution by right-clicking on any folder in the Solution Explorer and select "Add new file".

Comment: Well, I get that - and I do appreciate the info - but I'm more trying to understand WHY it works the way it does, and how to do it by hand so that Visual Studio is not auto-generating it for me. Automatic wiring is nice, and convenient sometimes - but I hate it personally. I like to know what is going on. I'm going to be reviewing whatnick's post and see what it explains.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a Silverlight Application and choose for it to create aHost the Silverlight Application in a Web site.

It will create a project that generates the page that contains silverlight object that loads the xap file on the client.

The xap file is located in the ClientBin, the xap file is the Silverlight application.

As long as you point the object source `<param>` to the path of the `xap` file, it should load the respective Silverlight App.

[image]

The project it creates:

[image]

Example aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>SilverlightApplication1</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #silverlightControlHost {
        height: 100%;
        text-align:center;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Silverlight.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onSilverlightError(sender, args) {
            var appSource = "";
            if (sender != null && sender != 0) {
              appSource = sender.getHost().Source;
            }

            var errorType = args.ErrorType;
            var iErrorCode = args.ErrorCode;

            if (errorType == "ImageError" || errorType == "MediaError") {
              return;
            }

            var errMsg = "Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application " +  appSource + "\n" ;

            errMsg += "Code: "+ iErrorCode + "    \n";
            errMsg += "Category: " + errorType + "       \n";
            errMsg += "Message: " + args.ErrorMessage + "     \n";

            if (errorType == "ParserError") {
                errMsg += "File: " + args.xamlFile + "     \n";
                errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
                errMsg += "Position: " + args.charPosition + "     \n";
            }
            else if (errorType == "RuntimeError") {           
                if (args.lineNumber != 0) {
                    errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
                    errMsg += "Position: " +  args.charPosition + "     \n";
                }
                errMsg += "MethodName: " + args.methodName + "     \n";
            }

            throw new Error(errMsg);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
          <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightApplication1.xap"/>
          <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
          <param name="background" value="white" />
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40818.0" />
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
          <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40818.0" style="text-decoration:none">
              <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
          </a>
        </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```